# Change textView value in viewpager from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am using a tabed view in my application...

my code...

```
public class ComboGraph extends AppCompatActivity {


Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_combo_graph);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "a");
    ExpensesGraph expensesGraph=(ExpensesGraph)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
            expensesGraph.textView.setText("Hello");


        }
    });


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ExpensesGraph(), "Expenses");
    adapter.addFragment(new IncomeGraph(), "Income");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

}
```

ExpenseGraph.java

```
public class ExpensesGraph extends Fragment {


TextView textView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_epenses_graph, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_fragment);
    return view;
}




}
```

Error log

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView com.pocketdiary.ExpensesGraph.textView' on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at com.gloesolutions.pocketdiary.ComboGraph$1.onClick(ComboGraph.java:44)

I need to change the textview from`expensgraph` activities value from `combograph` button click. Every method i tried getting null point error.
How can i solve this issue.?

Comment: post error logcat..

Comment: might wanna rephrase your question. I don't understand what you want. Are you trying to pass the text from ```onClick()``` to your fragment?

Comment: yes............

Comment: I need to change a textviews value inside a viewpager from activities button click.

Answer (score 3):

Create a BaseFragment for both  ExpensesGraph and IncomeGraph like below

```
  public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
       public abstract void updateComponent();
  }
```

In Activity  Button Onclick

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       (BaseFragment)viewPageAdaptor.getItem(0)).updateComponent();
    }
});
```

Inside the ExpensesGraph and IncomeGraph Fragments you need to update the TextView accordingly. Same call back if you want it in all fragment make it inside the loop.

Inside the Fragment

```
public class ExpensesGraph extends BaseFragment {

TextView textView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_epenses_graph, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_fragment);
    return view;
}

public void updateComponent(){
   if(textView != null){
      textView.setText("Update your text Here")
   }
}}
```

Comment: Can you explain.?

Comment: No luck...
I need to change a textviews value inside a viewpager from activities button click.

Answer (score 1):

you should call on replace method here `mFragmentList.add(fragment);` since  there is a possibility that `onCreateView` on your fragment will not be reinitialize

Comment: can you explain.?

Comment: from what I understand in your code, when you click the button in the tab view it will open the fragment right? this will call your method `mFragmentList.add(fragment);`. On first add of the fragment. it will initialize so it will run the `onCreateView`. When you go to other tab and open again the fragment, there is a possibility that it will not initialize because you add it again.To make sure it will initialize the view, you cann use `.replace` instead of `.add`. You can try to breakpoint it to make sure the view is initialize on `.replace` method.

Comment: I need to change a textviews value inside a viewpager from activities button click.

Answer (score 0):

you may create two methods getter and setter in activity eg. public String getDataToPass(){return requiredtext;} , public void setDataToPass(String requiredtext){ this.requiredtext = requiredtext;} , and onClick in fragment button, pass data to activity method eg. btn.onClick(){getActivity().setDataToPass("your text");}, finally on next fragment OnViewCreated : get text as String text = getActivity().getDataToPass();